# How do I stop someone from seeing me on Facebook Chat?

Tags: facebook, privacy, chat

I like [Facebook Chat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Chat), but I want to hide from specific people.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make a [friend list](http://www.facebook.com/friends/) of those you do not want to see you online by clicking on `Create New List`.

[image]
<sub>(source: [insidefacebook.com](http://www.insidefacebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/friendstab2.jpg))</sub>

You can then move those individuals to the list by clicking on `Add to List`.

[alt text http://mos.futurenet.com/techradar/classifications/computing/internet-and-broadband/images/facebookprivacy/flists-420-90.jpg](http://mos.futurenet.com/techradar/classifications/computing/internet-and-broadband/images/facebookprivacy/flists-420-90.jpg)

Click on `Chat` in the lower left corner.

[alt text http://www.socialtimes.com/wordpressnew/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/facebookfriendlist.jpg](http://www.socialtimes.com/wordpressnew/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/facebookfriendlist.jpg)

Then toggle the offline status (green toggle next to the list name) of that particular friend list.

Comment: Nice presentation!

Comment: @phwd But we would then be unable to see if those people in that list is online right.. how do we appear "invisible" ?