# Appear offline in Facebook chat and select one user with whom you would like to chat

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop someone from seeing me on facebook chat?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1169/how-do-i-stop-someone-from-seeing-me-on-facebook-chat)

I would like to open Facebook chat and see who is online, so that they can not see me. Then I would like to chat only with some specific person.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this person to a specific list, then hide the other lists